# How to send a UDP packet from a specific interface under Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, rust

I have several Ethernet interfaces with IPv4 Link-Local addresses, which means I have multiple routes to `169.254.0.0/16` on different interfaces. (Those interfaces are not necessarily on the same layer 2 network, so the same IP in this range can be used by different systems on different interfaces.)

When sending a UDP packet to an address in `169.254.0.0/16` I can't pick which interface will be used to send the packet using Rust's standard library `UdpSocket`, but without specifying the interface it is very likely to use the wrong one.

How can I send a UDP packet from a specific interface?

(IPv6 Link-Local `fe80::/64` has a similar problem, but `SocketAddrV6` has a `scope_id` which can be used to set the index of the interface to use).

Comment: *so I can't choose which* — why does this logically follow from the fact that they have the same mask/route/broadcast address? How would you do it if that were not the case?

Comment: I don't think Rust should handle that, you must configure your OS to route specific IP to specific interface.

Comment: untested idea: use an ipv4-mapped IPv6 address and add a scope identifier. If that doesn't work you'll probably have to use lower-level APIs to bind the socket to a device.

Comment: Usually the bind call assigning a transport address to a socket. I never used rust `UdpSocket` but I see there is a bind method. Have you already verified that it does not work in your scenario?

Comment: If they all have link-local addresses you can't send a UDP packet anywhere except to yourself anyway, so why do you care?

Comment: [RFC 3927, IPv4 Link-Local Addresses](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3927#section-3) warns in section 3 about the problems arising from using IPv4 Link-Local on multiple interfaces; it mainly lists the problems that need to be solved, but doesn't offer much in order to solve them. I'd recommend using IPv6 Link-Local instead where those problems are mostly solved (-> scope id).  If you have some C code someone might be able to help you port it to rust.

Comment: In the C socket API you can specify the interface for a socket, so I presume that is what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @starblue You mean `SO_BINDTODEVICE`? [socket(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) describes it as "only packets received from that particular interface are processed", but it's not clear to me whether it works for sending too. Or `IP_UNICAST_IF` (from windows, but I read some claims it got ported to linux for wine)?

Comment: @Stefan `SO_BINDTODEVICE`, and it also works for sending, if I remember correctly (it was in a commercial project and I don't have access to the code any more). A quick look into the Linux kernel seems to confirm that, though it is hard to be sure because everything in the network stack is so indirect.

Comment: Yes, I implemented `IP_UNICAST_IF` in the kernel for Wine - it has been supported since Linux 3.3.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know which local IP address belongs to which network, you can use `bind` to bind the socket to that IP address.

Comment: That is a good idea as long as you don't happen to use the same IP on multiple interfaces :) IIRC the "random generator" to pick an address is seeded with the MAC address, so using different MAC addresses should lower the odds, but there are still only `2^16` IPs in that network.

Comment: bind only works for receiving packets.  For sending UDP (datagram) packets, you are not required to bind to a socket.