# How can I send through a specific network interface?

Tags: linux, rust, gateway

I need send messages through different gateways dynamically. How do that and what must be my first step in this direction?

On my server I have two connections: one-direct, and secondary over VPN. Default route is direct connection, but i need dynamically change connection to VPN.

At current time I try build socket from `libc::bind()` it's work, but have not expected effect.

[Changing the outgoing IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368707/166275) is not a solution to define the interface.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408040/how-to-send-a-udp-packet-from-a-specific-interface-under-linux .

Comment: @starblue, I saw it. Issue was not accepted as resolved and is little bit other question.

Comment: rust don't have api at such low level networking, see your OS documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a comment we must use `SO_BINDTODEVICE`, and no way to escape FFI cause it used internally. 
Here working example:

```
extern crate libc;

use libc as c;
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::net::{TcpStream, SocketAddr};
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd;
use std::mem;

#[cfg(any(target_os = "linux"))]
fn connect_dev(addr: SocketAddr, link: &str) -> io::Result<TcpStream> {
    let (addr_raw, addr_len) = match addr {
        SocketAddr::V4(ref a) =>
            (a as *const _ as *const _, mem::size_of_val(a) as c::socklen_t),
        SocketAddr::V6(ref a) =>
            (a as *const _ as *const _, mem::size_of_val(a) as c::socklen_t),
    };

    unsafe {
        let fd = check_os_error(c::socket(c::AF_INET, c::SOCK_STREAM, 0))?;
        check_os_error(c::setsockopt(
            fd,
            c::SOL_SOCKET,
            c::SO_BINDTODEVICE,
            CString::new(link).expect("device name").as_ptr() as *const c::c_void,
            mem::size_of::<CString>() as c::socklen_t,
        ))?;
        check_os_error(c::connect(fd, addr_raw, addr_len))?;

        Ok(TcpStream::from_raw_fd(fd))
    }
}

#[cfg(any(target_os = "linux"))]
pub fn check_os_error(res: c::c_int) -> io::Result<c::c_int> {
    if res == -1 {
        Err(io::Error::from_raw_os_error(unsafe { *c::__errno_location()  as i32 }))
    } else {
        Ok(res)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different source IPs. I assume that you have your system configured to route different source IPs into different gateways  (if not, it's an operator problem, not a programmer). You can specify different source IP in `bind` function for socket. Normally you pass their 'default' value (0.0.0.0) which means 'anything OS find reasonable', but you can specify exact source IP for your task.

A C `bind` signature:

```c
int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

`addr` may contain the specific address.

Comment: Since this answer is the same as the answer to [How to send a UDP packet from a specific interface under Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50408040/155423), it's safe to assume you agree the questions are duplicates?

Comment: May be. To be honest, this topic requires some extensive operator-level explanation, including `gai.conf`, routing tables, policy-based routing, etc. Multihoming is a tricky topic, especially in ipv4 world.